# Solving cass-koopmans planning model with python value function iteration

Tags: macroeconomics, recursive-macroeconomics

edit: sorry, I used stack exchange first time, so I didn't know I can type python code. you can now copy and run the code.

I'm practicing solving economic model using python programming. I refer to
https://python.quantecon.org/optgrowth.html and
https://python.quantecon.org/optgrowth_fast.html.

I wanna solve Cass-Koopmans planning problem with bellman equation.

- There is only one agent who governs all resource allocations in the economy. She produces a (single) good through a production function:

  $$
  y_{t} = f(k_{t}) \tag{1}
  $$
- The good can be used for consumption and investment.
- In this exercise, we introduce a partial capital depreciation, i.e. capital depreciates at the rate $0<\delta<1$ each period. Hence the resource constraint for the agent is:

  $$
  k_{t+1} + c_t = y_t + (1-\delta)k_t \tag{2}
  $$
- The agent wants to maximize

  $$
  \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \beta^t u(c_t) \right] \tag{3}
  $$
  subject to (2), where $ \beta \in (0, 1) $ is a discount factor.
- The model is almost identical to Cass-Koopmans planning model. In order to solve this model, we will apply value function iteration algorithm. Hence, we first reformulate the maximization problem into a Bellman equation.

We can write the value function for the agent's utility maximization problem in the form of **Bellman equation**. In this exercise we will use capital ($k$) as state variable instead of output ($y$). The value function is defined as follows:

$$
v(k) = \max_{0 \leq c \leq y + (1-\delta)k}
\left\{ u(c) + \beta v(k') \right\} \tag{4}
$$
subject to
$$
k' = f(k) + (1-\delta)k - c 
$$

This formulation takes consumption ($c$) as control variable. For the computation below we will use the next period capital ($k'$) as control variable. Then (4) can be rewritten as follows:

$$
v(k) = \max_{0 \leq k' \leq y + (1-\delta)k}
\left\{ u\left(f(k) + (1-\delta)k - k'\right) + \beta v(k') \right\} \tag{5}
$$

Essentially we converted the constrained maximization problem in (4) into the unconstrained maximization problem in (5).

So I made my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numba import njit, float64
from numba.experimental import jitclass
from quantecon.optimize.scalar_maximization import brent_max
from interpolation import interp
```

```
opt_growth_data = [('α', float64),
                  ('β', float64),
                  ('γ', float64),
                  ('δ', float64),
                  ('grid',float64[:])]

@jitclass(opt_growth_data)
class OptimalGrowth_VI:
    def __init__(self, α=0.4, β=0.96, γ=2.0, δ=0.1, grid_max=10, grid_size=500):
        self.α, self.β, self.γ, self.δ = α, β, γ, δ
        self.grid = np.linspace(0.1, grid_max, grid_size)
        
    def f(self, k):
        return k**self.α

    def u(self, c):
        return c**(1 - self.γ) / (1 - self.γ)
    
    def objective(self, k, kp, v_array):
        f, u, β, δ = self.f, self.u, self.β, self.δ
        v = lambda x: interp(self.grid, v_array, x)
        
        return u(f(k)+(1-δ)*k-kp) + β*v(kp)
```

```
@njit
def T(v, og_VI):
    v_greedy = np.empty_like(v)
    v_new = np.empty_like(v)
    
    for i in range(len(og_VI.grid)):
        k = og_VI.grid[i]
        lower = 1e-10
        upper = og_VI.f(k) + (1-og_VI.δ)*k
        result = brent_max(og_VI.objective, lower, upper, args=(k,v))
        v_greedy[i], v_new[i] = result[0], result[1]
        
    return v_greedy, v_new
```

```
def solve_model_VI(og_VI, tol=1e-4, max_iter=1000, print_skip=20):
    v = og_VI.grid
    error = tol+1
    i=0
    
    while i < max_iter and error > tol:
        v_greedy, v_new = T(v, og_VI)
        error = np.max(np.abs(v - v_new))
        i += 1
        if i % print_skip == 0:
            print(f"Error at iteration {i} is {error}.")
        v = v_new
    
    if i == max_iter:
        print("Failed to converge!")

    if i < max_iter:
        print(f"\nConverged in {i} iterations.")

    return v_greedy, v_new
```

```
og_VI = OptimalGrowth_VI()
v_greedy, v_solution = solve_model_VI(og_VI)
plt.plot(og_VI.grid, v_greedy)
```

[image]
I thought that I made my code correctly, but it produced weird optimal k's graph.
Could you review my code and tell me what's wrong with my implementation? It's a nuisance, but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try fitting a curve instead of a line to your graph and I suspect you should be able to get the usual path. If you can post your code, I' ll take a look at it. You might also want to look into stack-overflow for this.

Comment: It would be great to add the code in readable font

Comment: Please instead of posting pictures of code copy code as `code` you can do that by using two ` around the code . I think most people who would be willing to help won’t want to waste time copying code from pictures to try to run it to see where the problem is

Comment: I made it runnable. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code you provided.

1. The problem seems to occur because, in those points, consumption turns negative and messes up with the utility function. So, in your Class `OptimalGrowth_VI` definition, I added the following piece for the `objective` method:

```
    def objective(self, k, kp, v_array):
        f, u, β, δ = self.f, self.u, self.β, self.δ
        v = lambda x: interp(self.grid, v_array, x)
        c = f(k)+(1-δ)*k-kp
        if c <= 0:
            u = -888 - 800 * abs(c)
        else:
            u = u(c)
        return u + β*v(kp)
```

Basically, if `c` is negative, it will return an extremely small utility, so the `brent_max` function will ignore it. (McCandless' treatment). After that, you will have the textbook curved policy function.

2. Another thing I noticed is that the policy function, according to the grid and parameters you defined, does not touch the 45-degree line. Perhaps the predefined grid does not contain the steady-state value. I increased your `grid_max= 50` and added a 45-degree line to check the convergence to the steady state.

```
og_VI = OptimalGrowth_VI()
v_greedy, v_solution = solve_model_VI(og_VI)
plt.plot(og_VI.grid, v_greedy)
# add 45 degree line
plt.plot(og_VI.grid, og_VI.grid, ls=':', label='45 degree line')
plt.xlabel('k(t)')
plt.ylabel('k(t+1)')
```

[image: policy function]